# Concatenating semicolon with string

Tags: php

Good day.

What I'm doing:

```
$str = "'"."a value"."'";
var_dump($str);
```

What I expect:

```
"'a value'"
```

What I recieve:

```
&#39;a value&#39;
```

Question: why? 
I am definitely NOT doing any transformation.

All values that are concatenated are strings, I've checked.

Output of the page sets header to be application/json, but I checked with text/html. Same result.

Tried shielding data as "\'", tried unhtmlspecialchars, tried json_decode. Same result.

magick_quotes - tried, not related, but tried. Same result.

Using Wamp(32) on Win7
php 5.3.13

UPDATE:

Just discovered that this happens ONLY in var_dump, while print_r and echo shows data as expected...

So - problem solved for a moment, but still - this is not a common behaviour, and an idea of - why it works that way would be appreciated.

Comment: *"What I recieve:

&#39;a value.&#39;"* - You sure it's not `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''";' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)`?

Comment: change your code to `$str = "'" . "a value.\"'"`;

Comment: Try `$str = "'a value.'";` var_dump => `string(10) "'a value.'" ` - echo => `'a value.'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- - just tried, got &#39;a value&#39; ...

Comment: We need to know how you're using it. My echo gave back `'a value.'` so, if you're using this in conjunction with a DB or other application, tell/show us.

Comment: No, it's in plain php script. 
THis exact part works trough require_once (a_class_definition), then creating a class instance, and in it's methods there is this code.

I simplified this code to one line, and still get this #$%^& instead of expected result...


My guess is that I'm missing something in php settings, but I have no ideas of what I'm missing...

Comment: Hmmmm, just removed everything, tried to do that from index.php (before all includes etc). Works as expected... @Fred-ii-  Thanks for a hint, gone digging.

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are misplaced:

```
$str = "'"."a value."'";
                    ^ here you close the " but you don't concatenate using .
```

Should be:

```
$str = "'" . "a value. " . "'" . "";
```

Although I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, you could write this string in easier ways than doing this, [example in sandobx](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a513c537d210c58db810c89e6adc80f19ab998ca).

Comment: I've added this quote that I've missed, and now code looks exactly as the one you proposed. What I'm saying is that THIS exact code doesn't work on my env for some reason. And I am wondering if anyone can give me any hints of why it can be so.

Comment: You are missing something that is relevant to this case then, as you can see from the sandbox link it works correctly, please update your question with more details.